# Testing an algorithm for safety in mutual exclusion

Tags: distributed-computing, distributed-system, mutex

I am attempting to write a code to test Lamport's Mutual Exclusion algorithm for safety as a correctness measure. I am running the alogrithm on a single core cpu machine with multiple processes sharing the same processor clock. One of ways I was planning to test was by recording the entry and exit times of each process in the critical section. So if there is no overlap between these times could I say that the algorithm satisfies safety requirement?